# LibreOffice / Excel: how to paste data with newline/endline characters inside a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to paste some data into a spreadsheet, but since the data contains `\n` characters within it, the cells below are overwritten. I want to paste the entire bit of data into a single cell.

Eg:

```
some \n
multiline \n
data
```

Needs to go into a single cell, rather than cells in 3 rows.

I'm interested in knowing how to do this for both LibreOffice and Excel.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well for a single insert, I would just use *F2* on the cell or enter it any other way, so you get the edit mode, then paste it.

Another way would be to use the formula-input at the top of the worksheets. Select your destiny cell, then select the formula-input, then paste.

Is is more complicated, when you have multiple multirow cells to insert.

Comment: btw does this also work for excel?

Comment: funny, I don't use LibreOffice - so yeah, my answer was based on excel ;)

Comment: ah OK - works for both then :D

Comment: One caveat for this approach is that, if your source text contains any formatting, such as **bold**, variations in font size, etc., those will not be retained. Still, it's the best solution available.